# The minimum reputation point for view-vote-count action changed?

Tags: support, reputation

Hi all,

Several days ago, I can easily click to any queston/answer to see the vote count (how many upvote/downvote on that question/answer). But's now it doesn't show up. So I guess the minimum reputation point to that priviledge has changed?

I know there's a page to view the priviledge, but don't know how to access it from the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to click on your *reputation number*:

[image: Reputation]

This don't work on [meta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/), only inside [main](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) stack site.

Comment: so it changed, thanks.

Comment: Once the site comes out of beta, it will likely change again.  [Rep Abilities Not Grandfathered in From Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta).